# How to use std::thread on Windows with MinGW with POSIX threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mingw, mingw-w64

I have been trying to compile and run the following very simple bit of code

```
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void thread_c() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        cout << i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t(thread_c);
    t.join();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling on Windows 10 with MinGW 6.3.0 (target x86_64-w64-mingw32) and the thread model (obtained using `g++ -v`) is POSIX.

I am not getting any compilation error with `g++ -Wall -g test.cpp -o test.exe`, however I am getting a runtime error when trying to run the exe (`entry point of _ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_3_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvve cannot be found`).

I also tried compiling with the `-pthread`or `-lpthread` flags, but I am getting the same runtime error.
Obviously this seems to be related to the use of std::thread, but I didn't get how to fix this. Am I missing a compilation flag or additional library enabling POSIX thread support on Windows?

**Edit:** I managed to get it working by changing the compilation command to
`g++ -Wall -g test.cpp -o test.exe -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -Wl,Bdynamic`

Comment: That's not a runtime error, it's a compile time error, precisely a linker error. That said, your code should never compile, there is no global `thread` class, it should be in a namespace. Is that really the code causing issues? BTW: MinGW 10 is out already, consider upgrading!

Comment: My bad, I forgot the using namespace std in the above code. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade MinGW as I am working in a profesionnal environment with no leverage on this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code after making the necessary fixes:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void thread_c() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t(thread_c);
    t.join();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and it worked fine.
The build command was the same as yours:

```bash
g++ -Wall -g test.cpp -o test.exe
```

The output was:

```
012345678910Press any key to continue . . .
```

But I did use MinGW-w64 GCC 12.1.0 (fro https://winlibs.com/) instead of the very old version 6.3.0.

Maybe the MinGW-w64 (or was it still the old MinGW) library you were using was simply too old...